# Display form error on the same line that the form field but error_bubbling is not working

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Form validation errors are displaying on the top of the form, but I would like to display next to the widget that generate the error. I thought it was why error_bubbling is for.

So here is my form building (I set the error to false even if I know that this is the default value, just to make sure ) :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user , array('attr' => array('novalidate' => 'novalidate')))
        ->add('Login', TextType::class , ['label' => 'Login :', 'error_bubbling' => 'false'])
        ->add('Password', TextType::class , ['label' => 'Mot de passe :', 'error_bubbling' => 'false'])
        ->add('Email', TextType::class , ['label' => 'Email :', 'error_bubbling' => 'false'])
        ->add('Firstname', TextType::class , ['label' => 'Prénom :' , 'error_bubbling' => 'false'])
        ->add('Lastname', TextType::class , ['label' => 'Nom :', 'error_bubbling' => 'false'])
        ->add('Enregistrer', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Enregistrer'])
        ->getForm();
```

Here is how I call my form in my twig template :

```
{% form_theme form 'form.html.twig' %}

{{ form(form) }}
```

And here is the form template :

```
{% block form_row %}

    <div>
  
        <span class="formLabel" style = "width:150px;display: inline-block;">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        </span>

        <span class="formWidget">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </span>

        A<span class="formErrors" style = "color:red;">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </span>B

    </div>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Result is :

[image]

I thought error_bubbling option would have display each error between A and B.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```php
{ form_errors(form.name) }} //where name is the form field name
```

Comment: But I want each error to be displayed close to its field, whatever his name is. I have many field.

Comment: How about if you add every form field
`{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.Login) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.Login) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
`